# Class Array Insert Function

Tags: c++, arrays, class, data-structures

So I am error checking the codes I learned from given data structure book.I found out the insert function
is causing error.Here is my code so far:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class list
{
    int Myarray[10];
    int Mysize;

    public:
        list(void)
        {Mysize=0;}

    bool Empty()
    {
        return Mysize==0;
    }

    void Display()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<Mysize;i++)
        {
          cout<<Myarray[i]<<"";
        }
    }

    void Insert(int item,int pos)
    {
        if(Mysize==10)
        {
            cout<<"Full";

        }
        if(pos<0 ||pos >Mysize)
        {
            cout<<"Error";

        }

        for(int i=Mysize;i>pos;i--)
        {
            Myarray[i]=Myarray[i-1];
        }

            Myarray[pos]=item;
            Mysize++;



    }


    void Erase(int pos)
    {
        if(Mysize==0)
        {
            cout<<"Empty";
            return;
        }

        if(pos<0 || pos>= Mysize)
        {
            cerr<<"Error";
            return;
        }

        for(int i=pos;i<Mysize;i++)
        {
            Myarray[i]=Myarray[i+1];
        }
            Mysize--;

    }
};
    int main()
    {
        list X;

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
cout<< "Inserting "<<i<<" at position "<<i/2<<endl;
X.Insert(i, i/2);


}
cout<<endl; 
X.Display();
cout <<"\nTry to insert at position -1" <<endl;
X.Insert(0, -1) ;
cout<<endl; 
X.Display();



cout << "\nTry to insert at position 10"<< endl;
X.Insert(0, 10);
cout<<endl; 
X.Display();
}
```

The result is:

```
Inserting 0 at position 0
Inserting 1 at position 0
Inserting 2 at position 1
Inserting 3 at position 1
Inserting 4 at position 2
Inserting 5 at position 2
Inserting 6 at position 3
Inserting 7 at position 3
Inserting 8 at position 4

135786420
Try to insert at position -1
Error
0135786420
Try to insert at position 10
Full
0
```

What I don't understand is that since I have the condition:

```
if(pos<0 ||pos >Mysize)
{cout<<"Error";}
```

Why is that when inserting 0 into -1 position which supposed to be invalid is also inserted as display
in the result?Furthermore when a value is inserted into 10th position it resets the whole array and becomes 0?Isn't it the condition in the Insert function should have terminate both these conditions?

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your `Insert` function. Or use an actual debugger to step through it statement by statement. The latter should make it very obvious what the problem is.

Comment: Change the type of `pos` to std::uint32_t, then you dont need to care about `pos<0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you always proceed to the 'for' loop afterwards. You need to either use: 'if', 'else if' and then put the 'for' in 'else' or simply return after printing 'full' or 'error'.
For example:

```
void Insert(int item,int pos)
{
    if(Mysize==10)
    {
        cout<<"Full";
    }
    else if(pos<0 ||pos >Mysize)
    {
        cout<<"Error";
    }
    else {
        for(int i=Mysize;i>pos;i--)
        {
            Myarray[i]=Myarray[i-1];
        }
        Myarray[pos]=item;
        Mysize++;
    }
}
```